# Why are UV Maps are "squared off" why is this easier?

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, uv-image-editor, texture-coordinates

In this youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-xF5d3esd0&t=204s he explains how you must square off the UV map and essentially entirely fill up the 2048 x 2048 square. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: I suppose it's useful in case the image texture is square, also you gain a bit of space, other than that I don't think it's necessary

Comment: The reason to "entirely fill up" a UV map as much as possible is for performance considerations - you've already loaded a whole 2048x2048 texture into memory - it would be wasteful (performance wise) to leave big empty (unused) sections.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos, I don't think the question you've linked has to do with Murth's question  ;)

Comment: Indeed it is a bit different, had not realized that. But it does come back knocking on the same door. If the UV layouts are not square why does the texture have to be square and not make it rectangular to fit the UV map?

Answer (score 1):

It's useful if you want to optimize the space, you'll take better advantage of the space if the islands are orthogonal. Also it may be useful in case the image texture is square. By the way you can use the *UV Squares* addon to make the islands orthogonal: Select the island, open the *N panel > UV Squares*, press on *To Grid By Shape*.

[image]

Comment: Is it better to keep all the UV maps squared out versus having it being simply unwrapped?

Comment: it is better 1) if you want to optimize the space 2) if you have square textures. Other than that you can keep as they are, there's no obligation to make them straight

Comment: Ok thank you I was just wondering if making the UV maps different shapes would affect the textures in a negative way

Comment: "making the UV maps different shapes", could you please precise what you mean?

Comment: if you want the texture shape to follow the UV shape (here it's a bent shape), it's ok, here I've just made it straight to show you how you can straighten a UV to make it follow straight lines